# What is this kind of numerical method called and what is the intuition behind it?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

To solve for x in the equation : 2^x=x^3,

$2^x=x^3$
establish x=f(x) which is
$x=2^{x/3}$
and iterate
$x_{n+1}=2^{x_{n}/3}$

What is this kind of numerical method called and what is the intuition behind it?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration

Comment: Wow thank you so much @StinkingBishop