# Given a difficult exponential equation such as $x^x+2x=5$ or $x^3=2^x$, can its exact value be solved? Or just the approach?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

It is of course possible to write exponential equations that are difficult for many of you to see, but is it possible to find the exact value? Or can they only be predicted by some method?

If we cannot find its exact value, what methods are available to approximate it?

$$x^x+2x=5$$

$$x^3=2^x$$

$$\text{etc.}$$

Comment: Please ask only one question per post; here you seem to want at least three answers?

Comment: they all have the same difficulty, they are similar

Comment: I'm especially curious about the first two.

Comment: They are very different from one another.

Comment: Such equations generally don't have solutions in closed form. You can get arbitrarily good approximate solutions by any of a number of techniques – Newton's Method is one of the simplest and one of the best. Every Calculus textbook tells you how to use Newton's Method (and there are pages devoted to it all over the web).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3898662/what-is-this-kind-of-numerical-method-called-and-what-is-the-intuition-behind-it and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163721/solve-for-x-2x-x3 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910250/solving-2x-x3-algebraically

Comment: $x^x=ax+b$ and $e^{x^r}=a x+b$ both have [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) expansions

Comment: Firstly, those are two very different problems. Secondly, most of the time there is no analytical way to solve these kinds of problems nor is there a closed form solution to them. You can get a reasonably close approximation for it using several different methods. One popular method is called Newton's algorithm, as described by Gerry above.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-az-ez-and-a-ln-z-z-have-no-elementary-inverse https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309691/equations-solvable-by-lambert-function/2527410#2527410

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the equations you mentioned with special functions such as the [Lambert W function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) aka Omega function $\operatorname{W}\left( x \right)$
and [Wright W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_omega_function) aka Wright Omega $\omega\left( x \right)$ function for x, e.g.:

$$
\begin{align*}
x^{3} &= 2^{x} ~~~~~\quad\qquad\qquad\mid\quad \cdot 2^{-x}\\
x^{3} \cdot 2^{-x} &= 1\\
x^{3} \cdot e^{- \ln\left( 2 \right) \cdot x} &= 1 ~~~\qquad\qquad\qquad\mid\quad \left(  \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
x \cdot e^{-\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3} \cdot x} &= 1 ~~~\qquad\qquad\qquad\mid\quad \cdot \left( 
-\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3} \right)\\
-\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3} \cdot x \cdot e^{-\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3} \cdot x} &= -\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3}\\
\left( -\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3} \cdot x \right) \cdot e^{-\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3} \cdot x} &= -\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3} ~~~~\quad\qquad\mid\quad \operatorname{W}\left(  \right)\\
-\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3} \cdot x &= \operatorname{W}\left( -\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3} \right) ~~\quad\mid\quad \cdot \left( -\frac{3}{\ln\left( 2 \right)} \right)\\
x &= -\frac{3 \cdot \operatorname{W}\left( -\frac{\ln\left( 2 \right)}{3} \right)}{\ln\left( 2 \right)}\\
x &\approx 1.3735 ~~~~\qquad\qquad\mid\quad \text{via using the main branch}\\
x &\approx 9.9395 ~~~\qquad\qquad\mid\quad \text{via using the branch } -1\\
\end{align*}
$$

However, many equations that contain exponential functions also have no (until now found) non-approximate solutions. The easiest way to find these solutions is usually using [Newton's method](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html), e.g.:

$$
\begin{align*}
x^{x} + 2 \cdot x = 5 &\quad\mid\quad -5\\
x^{x} + 2 \cdot x - 5 = 0 &\quad\mid\quad f\left( x \right) := x^{x} + 2 \cdot x - 5\\
x_{n + 1} = x_{n} - \frac{f\left( x_{n} \right)}{f'\left( x_{n} \right)}\\
x_{n + 1} = x_{n} - \frac{x_{n}^{x_{n}} + 2 \cdot x_{n} - 5}{x_{n}^{x_{n}} \cdot \left( \ln\left( x_{n} \right) + 1 \right) + 2} &\quad\mid\quad \text{chose some } x_{1} \text{ like } x_{1} := 1\\
\lim_{{n} \to{\infty}} x_{n + 1} = \lim_{{n} \to{\infty}} x_{n} - \frac{x_{n}^{x_{n}} + 2 \cdot x_{n} - 5}{x_{n}^{x_{n}} \cdot \left( \ln\left( x_{n} \right) + 1 \right) + 2} \approx 1.5349 &\\
\end{align*}
$$